# C++: Using inner typedef if available in traits class or default

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I'm currently writing a template that operates differently based on the category of the input.

There are 3 cases I'm looking to add to my traits class.

> A. The type has a typedef `type_category`, use that.
>
> B. The type doesn't have the typedef, use the type `regular_tag` (most common case)
>
> C. My specializations, `std::list<T>` uses the type `special_tag` for any `T`.

How would I manage this? It's simple to do either A. and C. or B. and C. but I'm not sure how to get all 3.

## EDIT

A example might make it easier to understand.

```
class Foo
{
    typedef foo_tag type_category;
}
class Bar;

my_traits<Foo>::type(); // makes a foo_tag
my_traits<Bar>::type(); // makes a regular_tag
my_traits<std::list<Baz>>::type(); // makes a special_tag because I want special list proce
```

ssing.

Comment: You'll want SFINAE for A and B.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by C though.  Can you clarify C?  Maybe some pretend code at least?

Comment: That edit clarifies things.  Kerrek has an awesome answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scaffolding could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyTrait
{
  typedef typename MyHelper<T, CheckForType<T>::value>::type tag;
};

template <typename T>
struct MyTrait<std::list<T>>
{
  typedef special_tag tag;
};
```

We need the helper:

```
template <typename T, bool>
struct MyHelper
{
  typedef regular_tag tag;
};
template <typename T>
struct MyHelper<T, true>
{
  typedef typename T::type_category tag;
};
```

Now all we need is a type-trait to check for a member typedef:

```
template<typename T>
struct CheckForType
{
private:
    typedef char                      yes;
    typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

    template<typename C> static yes test(typename C::type_category*);
    template<typename C> static no  test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Usage:

```
MyTrait<Foo>::tag
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect. Does exactly what I want.

Comment: You can merge the helper into the traits using default parameters... change `bool` to `bool = CheckForType<T>::value`.

Comment: You can even make it a macro! `#define DECLARE_TYPEDEF_TRAITS(TYPEDEF, DEFAULT) template<class T> struct TYPEDEF##_trait_checker { private: template<class C> static char(&test(typename C::TYPEDEF *))[2]; template<class> static char(&test(...))[1]; public: static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) > 1; }; template<class T, bool = TYPEDEF##_trait_checker<T>::value> struct TYPEDEF##_trait { typedef DEFAULT type; }; template<class T> struct TYPEDEF##_trait<T, true> { typedef typename T::TYPEDEF type; }` ... then use it like `DECLARE_TYPEDEF_TRAITS(cheap_copy_reference, int);`

Answer (score 1):

The code by Kerrek works, but the following code is shorter and more versatile:

```
template <typename T,typename DefaultType>
class MyTrait
{
    template <typename C> static DefaultType               test( ... );
    template <typename C> static typename C::type_category test( typename C::type_category * );
public:
    using type = decltype( test<T>(nullptr) );
};
```

The reason I say that Kerrek's code is not versatile is that it requires you to hard-code the type "special_tag" so your class MyTrait will always use the same default tag. The code that I provide would allow you to use the class MyTrait with different defaults. For instance, it might happen that somewhere in the code, you want the default to be a **int** if the **type_category** is not defined, but elsewhere, you want it to be a **float**.

Let's look at an example. Suppose we design a class which is meant to take a container class such as the standard library **vector** as a template parameter. In our class, we want to use the same **size_type** as the underlying container. However, it might happen that somebody gives us a container that does not have **size_type** defined (for instance, a **valarray** does not define **size_type**). In this case, let's pretend I want to use **int** as the default (you should probably use **size_t** like the other standard containers, but if I changed the code you wouldn't be able to tell that the code is actually working). For this scenario I changed the classname from "MyTrait" to "size_typeof", and I changed the "type_category" to "size_type" (since this is the thing I want to look for). Some code for this scenario along with an example main function to see the types of the determined variables are given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <valarray>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T,typename DefaultType>
class size_typeof
{
    template <typename C> static DefaultType           test( ... );
    template <typename C> static typename C::size_type test( typename C::size_type * );
public:
    using type = decltype( test<T>(nullptr) );
};

template <typename ContainerType>
class Matrix {
    private:
        // Change int to size_t in real code. 
        using size_type = typename size_typeof<ContainerType,int>::type;
        size_type Rows;
        size_type Cols;
    public:
        Matrix( size_t rows, size_t cols ) : Rows(rows), Cols(cols) {}
        size_type rows(){ return Rows; }
        size_type cols(){ return Cols; }
};

int main()
{
    // Give the matrices some nonzero dimensions
    Matrix<std::vector<double>> vec(5,2);
    Matrix<std::valarray<double>> val(4,3);

    // vectors have a size_type, almost always defined as size_t. 
    // So this should return your compiler's code for size_t 
    // (on my computer, this is "m")
    std::cout << typeid( vec.rows() ).name() << std::endl; 

    // valarrays do not have a size_type. 
    // So this should return your compiler's code for int 
    // (on my computer, this is "i")
    // It should return this code, since we used int as the default  
    // size_type in the Matrix class
    std::cout << typeid( val.rows() ).name() << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Ok. That's great. But suppose I really did want to use just a hard-coded default for the DefaultType, instead of having to specify the DefaultType as a template parameter. Guess what? Template parameter defaults. Just define size_typeof like:

```
template <typename T,typename DefaultType = int>
class size_typeof {
    ...
};
```

and you are good to go. No need to specify the default type "int" anymore. For instance, in our Matrix class, we could have used

```
using size_type = size_typeof<ContainerType>;
```

The end.

Comment: that requires c++11, whereas the accepted answer works with c++03

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> 
T::type_category getType(T t, typename T::type_category c=typename T::type_category()) 
{ return c;}
template<class T> 
regular_tag getType(T t, ...) 
{ return regular_tag();}
template<class T>
special_tag getType(std::list<T> t, typename std::list<T>::type_category c=typename std::list<T>::type_category()) 
{ return special_tag();}

int main() {
    auto a = getType(int);
    auto b = getType(std::iterator_traits<char*>);
    auto c = getType(std::list<char>);
}
```

I'm not that great with SFINAE, so I doubt this even compiles, but something like this is the direction to look.